# Instancia de servidores de sql server management 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hice una instalación de SQL Server Management Studio 2017  en su Release  17.4, lo que ocurre es que ingreso al SQL e intento ingresar con el servidor local y no me deja ingresar; al inspeccionar el Administrador de configuraciones de SQL no sale ningún servidor instalado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al mirar los servicios de windows no aparecen servicios de SQL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ingresar al SQL  sale el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.Que puedo hacer para tener instancias de servidor local(.) y poderme conectar?

2.Debo de instalar SQL Server Express o que debo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Ciertamente debes instalar SQL Server para ello. Te recomiendo la versión developer, es gratuita para fines de aprendizaje.

[Descarga SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads#)

Elige la opción "SQL Server 2017 on-premises"

Muchísima suerte

Answer (score 0):

una solución que encontré fue, **ejecutar como administrador**